# Really really stumped on a $_POST PHP Issue

Tags: php, post, odbc

I'm building a CMS and I'm trying to make a versioning system.

Every time a user posts an update to an existing webpage, i want the 'Versioning' table to keep an event log of which fields have been edited...

to do this, i run a bunch of loops to check if the contents of the form that the user has just filled in is different to the contents on the website prior to their clicking submit...

therefore, before i do any updating i have the following code (apologies if the formatting is askew):

```
$sql = "select * from pages where ID =" .$_POST[id];
$rs = odbc_exec ($db, $sql);
$contents_original = odbc_result($rs,"content");
$title_original = odbc_result($rs,"title");
$pageorder_original = odbc_result($rs,"pageorder");
$parent_original = odbc_result($rs,"parent");
$footer_original = odbc_result($rs,"footer");

$updated_content = trim(stripslashes(strtolower(htmlentities($_POST['content']))));
$original = trim(strtolower($contents_original));

if ($updated_content == $original) {
                $a = 'n';
                } else {
                $a = '<p>Contents changed.';
                }
```

// and so on from variable $b - $e  ... then:

```
    $update = "$a $b $c $d $e";
```

Which is then followed by the updating routines (all of which work fine and dandy), and at the end of the Versions update, i insert the contents of $update into the SQL in the 'events' column (this also works just fine)

However!  supposing a user loads up the form with the original page content and clicks submit... if nothing has changed to the form then $a would = ' ' and, therefore, nothing should be input into the 'events' column.  Except it keeps inputting 'contents changed' and, in fact, does so for every single string (e.g. the title field, the footer field etc.)!  the odd thing is there are 2 integer inputs and they are recorded by the events menu just fine.

If i print out strlen(stripslashes(strtolower(htmlentities($_POST['content'])))) and strlen(strtolower($contents_original)) it reveals that the lengths are different...

there is nothing in either the code or the database length to cause this inhibition.

---

OUTPUT FROM:
stripslashes(strtolower(stripcslashes($thenewcontent)))

hello from the octopus!

welcome to jonathan m. edwards' graphic design page.

whatever you need designing - a business website, a band logo, you name it - i have the skills to provide you with a creative and professional product.

click on the thumbnails below to have a quick browse:

to arrange for a quote or if you simply want to talk an idea through, drop me an email at: contact[at]angry-octopus.co.uk or call me on (0789)694-3379

---

OUTPUT FROM
stripslashes(strtolower(html_entity_decode($contents_original)))

hello from the octopus!

welcome to jonathan m. edwards' graphic design page.

whatever you need designing - a business website, a band logo, you name it - i have the skills to provide you with a creative and professional product.

click on the thumbnails below to have a quick browse:

to arrange for a quote or if you simply want to talk an idea through, drop me an email at: contact[at]angry-octopus.co.uk or call me on (0789)694-3379

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ALL THE ABOVE COPY/PASTED FROM A NOTEPAD .TXT.

Comment: Your code is highly vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Why don't you use firebug to look at the actual messages going back and forth?

Comment: It should be hidden and encoded. it's not on the default domain page.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `htmlentities()`, the string might be longer because of character conversion. Or shorter because you also use `stripslashes()`. (thx Jorge)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm afraid that doesn't work! the numbers are still out.  I've had a good experiment with various string functions but nothing seems to get the submission and the database field bang on the same...

Answer (score 0):

is the data in the database multi byte,

in case the data is unicode ( multi byte ), the normal strlen functions dont work well, as they would count the string as single byte

you can try using the function :

```
mb_strlen (strtolower($contents_original)) )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Also the best way to read the changes is by saving in a notepad (file) and opening it in an editor that has no encoding, there you would realize the issue..

Comment: I gave that a try, it did alter the numbers a little but they still didn't match, I also checked the same result with mb_check_encoding and it came up with a '1' I don't know if that confirms that the database is indeed a multibyte database but it implies that it probably is...

Comment: Aroha Labs, i'll try it in an editor. I'm beginning to lose hope! I've been working on these silly lines of code for hours haha!

Comment: it looks identical. The database is UTF-8 so i changed that in my PHP as it was set to ANSI... no difference either... (see edit above)

Comment: did you try trimming any whitespaces, what output does strlen and mb_strlen show you..